# Object oriented programming turtle (python)

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to get two turtles on a screen. So far I have this:

```
import turtle 
t1 = turtle.Turtle() 
t2 = turtle.Turtle() 
t1.color("red") 
t2.color("blue") 
t1.forward(20) 
t2.right(90) 
t2.forward(100)
```

But nothing is happening :(

Im using the Turtle IDE downloaded from:http://pythonturtle.org/

All i want to do is illustrate some object orientation but if that code wont work, i cant

Anyone got any suggestions (ive tried using turtles API but its hard to follow)

Thanks

Comment: Did you try with one turtle? What happens?
Did you try to run python directly and typing these lines (without IDE)?

Comment: It works perfectly with one turtle on the IDE but no avail with two turtles.

Comment: When I run that code (pasted into the commandline), everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

**You didn't take an object from the class Screen**

You should do that to make sure that the window will not close immediately, plus you should make the program loop.

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()   # taking window object from Screen class
t1 = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t1.color("red")
t2.color("blue")
t1.forward(20)
t2.right(90)
t2.forward(100)

while True:         # Making the program loop to make the program continue running.
    wn.update()
```

**The main loop also you can make it this way**

```
wn.mainloop()
```

I recommend you follow the first solution.